# Dropdown box selected with php and database

Tags: php, database, select, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm making a simple program in which you can add things to a database, and get the information out of it again. I can't figure this out though. I made a simple script which makes a dropbox from data out of the database. However, it doesnt matter which option you select, since it always puts the last variable in the database. I can't figure out how I can make is so the option you select gets put into the database. I hope you guys can help me!
This is the program:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$sloep = $row['Naam'];
echo "<option value=". $sloep .">". $sloep ."</option><br>";
}
echo "</select>";

// Puts info in the database.

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "De informatie staat erin.";
$sql = "INSERT INTO Roeiers (Naam, Sloep) VALUES ('".$naam."', '".$sloep."')";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Greetz, 
Rick

Answer (score 0):

The values `$naam` and `$sloep` are never changed by the user.

Try :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "De informatie staat erin.";
$sql = "INSERT INTO Roeiers (Naam, Sloep) VALUES ('".$_POST["submit"]."', '".$_POST["submit"]."')";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

However, you should do some cleaning on `$_POST["submit"]` since your code is open to sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<select name="fieldName">
<option value="blah">blah</option>
<option value="blah2">blah2</option>
<option value="blah3">blah3</option>
</select>
<?php

$val = $_POST['fieldName'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "De informatie staat erin.";
// PLEASE READ : Replace POST variable with correct field names
$sql = "INSERT INTO Roeiers (Naam, Sloep) VALUES ('".$_POST['Naam']."', '".$_POST['fieldName']."')";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```